# Adding a string based off of the first character in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

Well, for some reason this seemed like a really simple question, but I can't find any answers on how to do something like this on here.  I have a dataframe with a column with several types of strings.  I need to go through the column, see which ones begin with 'M', then if they do, add the string '01' to the end of them.

I am so close, but I can't seem to get this applied to my actual dataframe.  I can't seem to use a return in my for loops, and I'm not really sure how I could write this using a lambda function.  (which is typically what I do)

This for loop I wrote prints the correct output.  I am just not sure how to apply this to my dataframe and change the data in the column.

```
for i in main_data['Payor_ID_Number']:
    if i != '':
        if i[0] == 'M':
            print(str(i + '01'))
```

Sorry about the basic question, I'm still learning.

Also, I would give big props if someone could write this into a function, as I'm not very good at writing those, yet and I would like to see how it would be done.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can use [str.startswith()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html):

```
main_data.loc[main_data['Payor_ID_Number'].str.startswith('M'), 'Payor_ID_Number'] += '01'
```